AWS Amplify GraphQL Code Generation Error: "Invalid or incomplete schema, unknown type: AWSModelQueryMap"
I am working on a React project using AWS Amplify Gen 1 and attempting to set up a GraphQL API. I have initialized my Amplify project and added a GraphQL API using the default To-do List schema. However, when trying to push the schema and generate the required code, I am encountering errors.
[adonys@DESKTOP-LO73D5J react-aws-amplify]$ amplify push
⠇ Fetching updates to backend environment: dev from the cloud.⠋ Building resource api/reactawsamplify
⚠️  WARNING: your GraphQL API currently allows public create, read, update, and delete access to all models via an API Key. To configure PRODUCTION-READY authorization rules, review: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules

⠸ Building resource api/reactawsamplify✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /home/adonys/react-aws-amplify/amplify/backend/api/reactawsamplify/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /home/adonys/react-aws-amplify/amplify/backend/api/reactawsamplify/schema
✔ Successfully pulled backend environment dev from the cloud.
⠋ Building resource api/reactawsamplify
⚠️  WARNING: your GraphQL API currently allows public create, read, update, and delete access to all models via an API Key. To configure PRODUCTION-READY authorization rules, review: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules

⠸ Building resource api/reactawsamplify✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /home/adonys/react-aws-amplify/amplify/backend/api/reactawsamplify/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /home/adonys/react-aws-amplify/amplify/backend/api/reactawsamplify/schema

    Current Environment: dev
    
┌──────────┬─────────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Category │ Resource name   │ Operation │ Provider plugin   │
├──────────┼─────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Api      │ reactawsamplify │ Create    │ awscloudformation │
└──────────┴─────────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────┘
✔ Are you sure you want to continue? (Y/n) · yes

⚠️  WARNING: your GraphQL API currently allows public create, read, update, and delete access to all models via an API Key. To configure PRODUCTION-READY authorization rules, review: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules

✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /home/adonys/react-aws-amplify/amplify/backend/api/reactawsamplify/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /home/adonys/react-aws-amplify/amplify/backend/api/reactawsamplify/schema
⠋ Building resource api/reactawsamplify
⚠️  WARNING: your GraphQL API currently allows public create, read, update, and delete access to all models via an API Key. To configure PRODUCTION-READY authorization rules, review: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules

⠹ Building resource api/reactawsamplify✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /home/adonys/react-aws-amplify/amplify/backend/api/reactawsamplify/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /home/adonys/react-aws-amplify/amplify/backend/api/reactawsamplify/schema
? Do you want to generate code for your newly created GraphQL API Yes
? Choose the code generation language target typescript
? Enter the file name pattern of graphql queries, mutations and subscriptions src/graphql/**/*.ts
? Do you want to generate/update all possible GraphQL operations - queries, mutations and subscriptions Yes
? Enter maximum statement depth [increase from default if your schema is deeply nested] 2
? Enter the file name for the generated code src/API.ts

Deployment completed.
Deploying root stack reactawsamplify [ ---------------------------------------- ] 0/2
        amplify-reactawsamplify-dev-5… AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS             Sun Nov 10 2024 20:36
        apireactawsamplify             AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     CREATE_IN_PROGRESS             Sun Nov 10 2024 20:36
Deployed api reactawsamplify [ ======================================== ] 6/6
        GraphQLAPI                     AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi       CREATE_COMPLETE                Sun Nov 10 2024 20:36
        GraphQLAPIDefaultApiKey215A6D… AWS::AppSync::ApiKey           CREATE_COMPLETE                Sun Nov 10 2024 20:36
        GraphQLAPITransformerSchema3C… AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema    CREATE_COMPLETE                Sun Nov 10 2024 20:37
        GraphQLAPINONEDS95A13CF0       AWS::AppSync::DataSource       CREATE_COMPLETE                Sun Nov 10 2024 20:36
        Todo                           AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     CREATE_COMPLETE                Sun Nov 10 2024 20:37
        CustomResourcesjson            AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     CREATE_COMPLETE                Sun Nov 10 2024 20:37

Code generation failed with the following error 
Invalid or incomplete schema, unknown type: AWSModelQueryMap. Ensure that a full introspection query is used in order to build a client schema..
Deployment state saved successfully.

Additional Context:

AWS Amplify CLI version: 12.13.0
Node.js version: v20.15.0
React project using TypeScript
Using the default "To-do List" template from Amplify

I'm unsure why this error related to AWSModelQueryMap is occurring, especially since I'm using the default schema provided by Amplify. Could it be related to outdated configurations, or is there something else I'm missing?
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

I'm seeing the same exact error!

Amplify v12.13.0
node v18.19.1


We encounter the same problem on front end as well regarding this AWSModelQueryMap type issue.
We updated the amplify pckg to the latest one which was released 3 days ago ( 6.8.3 ) and it solved the problem.

Try the following:
amplify api udpate

Then...
amplify push --yes

Optionally, you can add a set of flags to ensure graphql changes do take place
amplify push --minify --allow-destructive-graphql-schema-updates --force --yes


This did the trick!

This issue started happening to us yesterday with no changes in code; probably some dependent library issue.
The problem happens when you run amplify codegen

I have got this response from AWS Support:

I have received an update from the team indicating that the issue was
due to a recent update of the AppSync service, and they have rolled
back the changes. We have tested this on our end and it is functioning
properly now. Please feel free to test it on your end and let me know
if the issue persists.

